# iOS xib loaded at app start is not centered vertically

Tags: ios, user-interface, view, nib, xib

I have an iOS app that loads a xib file for the UI. When I first load the app the interface is about thirty pixels higher than it should be. In the app if I go down one screen and then come back to my main UI it's lined up how it should be.

Right now my view controller is subclassing UIViewController and in the app delegate it loads the nib using initWithNib:

Any ideas what I could do to get the first load to be properly centered on screen?

Answer (score 0):

Within Interface Builder check the actual size of the view in question. I've found when you add and remove simulated elements on a view, such as the status bar, this can cause the height to be reduced but not always increased.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, that did it. The only thing that you have to watch is if you have the status bar or any other extra bars turned on in Interface Builder, it won't let you change the size of the view.

I tried to vote up your answer, Dave, but I'm too new to.